# Querying Dynamo DB with out hash or Range Key using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to query `dynamodb` without using `hash key or range key` using **java SDK**, I searched in **AWS docs**, I didn't found any where.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation, you [must provide a hash key.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)

> You must provide a hash key attribute name and a distinct value to
>   search for. You can optionally provide a range key attribute name and
>   value, and use a comparison operator to refine the search results.

If you do not have the hash key, you should look into the [`Scan`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operation. It evaluates every item in your table for your conditions, as well as [other considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html).

Comment: Also note that, while the scan operation can do what OP is asking, it does use throughput for every item returned, and as such is very inefficient and discouraged, especially on larger tables.  Generally, scan is only recommended for backup purposes. (I'm sure this is mentioned in the documentation, but it can't be stressed enough).